# why the value of an array could be changed by another variable

Tags: go

the array in golang is value type. In my understanding, value type save the value, but not a memory address. So the following code, variable `arr` shouldn't be changed. but it no. I want know why

```
func main() {
    arr := []int{0,0,0}
    arr2 := arr

    arr[1] = 1

    fmt.Println(arr, arr2)
    // output [0 1 0] [0 1 0]
    // output in thought [0 0 0] [0 1 0]
}
```

maybe this is a basic question. But I found some article. they all just said which are reference types and value types in golang. But it couldn't help me to solve my problem.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You are using a slice, not an array. In your program, both `arr` and `arr2` are slices pointing to the same array. Change it so that:

```
    arr := [3]int{0,0,0}
```

Then, `arr` is an array, and it works as you expect.